# springboot switched one day back (-1) after reading from db (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, date

I am developing application, which will have different timezone users data.
So I planned to store the date and datetime in UTC (MYSQL)

In application level I have set the timezone as UTC using below lines of code at the start time application startup,

```
`@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // It will set UTC timezone
        System.out.println("Spring boot application running in UTC timezone :"+ new Date());   // It will print UTC timezone
    }`
```

While storing the date's and datetimes its stored properly in the database.

But when I retrieve the data from the database its always coming less than one day.

For eg.

I have two columns (created_date and created_datetime) in the table called users
created_date -> stores only date - 2023-06-13
created_datetime -> stores date and time - 2023-06-13 10:49:09

when I retrieve the data using JPA created_datetime column value is coming as it is, but created_date column value is coming as 2023-06-12 (-1 day)

In the entity level i have used LocalDate for created_date and LocalDateTime for created_datetime,

Below is my mysql timezone details

```
`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`
```

[Mysql TimeZone Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhUPg.png)

application.properties file i am using below values

*spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**********?connectionTimeZone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC*

I am using *mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar.*

My entity class

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDate createdDate;

    @Column(name = "created_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private LocalDate updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_datetime")
    private LocalDateTime updatedDateTime;
}
```

I have tried so many things, but nothing resolved my issue.
Please give your solutions/suggestions

Comment: Can you provide the entity? Are you using any custom Serializer/Deserializer class?

Comment: @mahfujasif edited the question and added entity class

Comment: Date without time is a mess when timezone is involved as a date is assume to be at a fixed time of day (midnight I believe). And a UTC date is actually not the same date in Australia as it is in California. You already have the datetime so I would remove the date and use datetime to get the correct date.